# Unauthorized accounts are able to push to my GitHub repository

Tags: git, authentication, github

I have two GitHub profiles. I created a repository using one and created a token through my IDE (PyCharm) and GitHub for the other account so that it can push commits. I had some successful pushes and merges from the other account which makes sense because I had provided a token.

Here is the unexpected part. As part of an experiment, I revoked **all** generated tokens on GitHub. After doing so, my other account was still able to push to the repo! Being very surprised by this result, I continued the experiment as follows: I ran `git config user.email` inside the local repo folder to update the email address to a nonsense email address that I'm pretty sure does not exist. Even after this change, I was still able to use `git push` to push changes to my remote on GitHub. That is, I can see the changes on GitHub. Any idea why that is? Two notes, just in case:

1. During the entire experiment, I was using a single computer (my laptop). Could it be that the generated tokens are stored somewhere and are being used no matter what the current user email address is? Again, all the generated tokens are revoked on the remote (GitHub).
2. There is only one branch, `master`, on both my local and remote.

Comment: The email on your commits isn't your "account". Your SSH key is.

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful. I guess I am using tokens and not SSH.

Answer (score 4):

`user.name` and `user.email` don't control any sort of authentication parameters.  The former is a personal name, and the latter is an email address, and they control the name and email address placed in commits you create, either as the author or committer.

Now, GitHub does associate commits with your account based on the email address, but you can push commits for any account (or any email address) to GitHub assuming you have access to the repository.  That's because many workflows involve a central maintainer who applies patches from someone and then pushes them to the repository.

As for authentication, if you're using SSH, then the tokens are not used at all.  The SSH key you're using is used to authenticate you without a token.  You can see the URL, which will tell you the kind of remote, by running `git remote -v`, which will either start with `https://` for an HTTPS remote or `ssh://` or `git@` for an SSH remote.

If you're using HTTPS, it may be that PyCharm is issuing tokens because it's an OAuth app or GitHub App.  Those types of apps can issue tokens that don't appear in the web interface because the web interface only shows personal access tokens, and those aren't personal access tokens.

The general approach to [deleting stored passwords and tokens for HTTPS is outlined in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-reset-credentials).  However, it may be that PyCharm doesn't use a normal credential helper and therefore you may need to expire it by hand using its own tools.

Comment: Thank you! The `git remote -v` listed two `https` links for fetch and push. I tried following the command in the link you provided. but the format `https://author@git.example.org` seems unfamiliar to me. The URL I am seeing is something like `https://github.com/<user_name>/<repo_name>.git`. Do you know how to convert one format to the other? Also, can you please provide a bit more information on what the value of `author`  should be?

BTW, I am able to run `git push` using a terminal outside PyCharm. Does that help rule out the last requirement you mentioned on working manually with PyCharm?

Comment: I think I figured out the format: `https://<repo_owner>@git.<repo_name>.org` . The issue seems to be fixed now. I am prompted to log in to GitHub when I run `git push` now.

Comment: I have a follow-up question. The above approach seems to be applicable to the **user** and not the remote. (I ran it on the terminal on my laptop, not on the GitHub website.) There must be a way for the **remote** (admin of the repository) to prevent pushes from any given user almost instantaneously. Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: The remote, GitHub, does prevent pushes from any user.  Only authorized users can push.  However, the credentials you were using were indeed authorized to push because they were for a different user that was authorized.

Comment: Thank you. I agree. The credentials were authorized to push. But what if the owner changes their mind. Is there any way to limit the ability of a user to push (almost) instantaneously? I was hoping this can be achieved simply by "revoking" the issued token on GitHub.

Comment: You can revoke your own personal access tokens at any time.  The owner of the repository can also change the permissions for who else is allowed to push at any time.  In your case, your token is likely issued by a GitHub App or OAuth app, in which case, you can remove that app from your account, and that will revoke its access.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that a user can remove its credentials. A question I am wondering about is how the _owner_ can deprive a user of pushing new changes to the repository. It looks like once a **token** is issued it will inevitably email valid until its expiration date. Any thoughts?

Comment: Personal access tokens can be revoked through the interface.  It sounds like in your case, you're using a different type of token issued by an app, which means you need to revoke that app to revoke that token's access to the repository.  If you don't, the app can just issue new tokens for your repository anyway.  Ultimately, you probably need to find out what kind of token it was and what kind of app, and ask a new question about how to revoke them, since the comments aren't really for extended discussion.

Comment: Thank you. Even though I used PyCharm, during the process, I was prompted to log in to the GitHub website. There, I was asked to create a Personal Access Token. As I shared earlier, at some point, I proceeded to revoke the token from the very page I had generated it. Surprisingly, even though the token disappeared from the webpage, it continued to allow pushing changes to the repository. I agree I should perhaps open up a new question that directly asks about the _effect of revoking personal access tokens using the "Revoke All" button on the GitHub website_.

Answer (score 1):

> Could it be that the generated tokens are stored somewhere and are being used even no matter what the current user email address is?
>
> The git remote -v listed two https links for fetch and push.

Then check which credential is currently cached by the credential helper

```
git config --global credential.helper
xxxx  <= take note of that value

# replace xxx by that value
prinft "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git credential-xxx get
```

If it is the credential of the wrong account, delete it with:

```
prinft "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=WrongAccount" | git credential-xxx erase
```

Comment: Thank you. But does that not mean we are relying on the "wrong user" to go ahead and remove their credentials? Is there any way that the owner of the project can terminate the access of the wrong user? I was hoping this can be achieved by revoking all generated tokens on GitHub.

Comment: BTW, I got `manager-core` as the value of xxx.

Comment: The owner can remove collaborators, but they cannot invalidate other users' tokens

Comment: I am just thinking hypothetically, but what if the user is an ex-employee? Shouldn't there be a way to instantaneously limit their authorization of pushing to GitHub?

Comment: Yrs, by removing the ex employee GitHub account as a collaborator, or a member of your organization. No more push possible.

Comment: Thank you. To wrap up, it seems like "instantaneous termination" is available only for collaborators and organization members. It is NOT available for tokens. Tokens will inevitably remain valid until their expiration date arrives. Did I get it right?

Comment: If the above is true, this makes me wonder what "revoking" a token on **GitHub** does exactly?!

Comment: @HD Those token are only there for authentication. If they authenticate you as a user who is no longer a collaborator or an organisation member, then you have effectively and immediately removed their write access (or, in the case of private repository, even their read access).

Comment: I think tokens can allow people to push to a repository even when they are neither a collaborator nor an organization member. That is the case in the experiment I described here. A related point is that when we create a token, we are explicitly asked about the level of access the token is supposed to encode.

Comment: @HD only a deploy token would allow that, but you do not communicate or give deploy token to people. Regular token do not allow access if you are not a collaborator.

Comment: @HD plus deploy tokens (aka [deploy keys](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys) are tied to the repository, so the owner can invalidate them immediately (in case they were compromised/given to other people).

Comment: What I created was a [Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) which seems not to be a deploy token. Do you agree? Also, there is a button "Revoke All" on the top right corner of the tokens page on GitHub. After pressing that button, all existing tokens disappeared, but still, my other account was able to push changes to my repository as described in the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245941/discussion-between-vonc-and-h-d).